# Firebase cloud function send object back to C# IDictionary with wrong order

Tags: c#, google-cloud-functions

As the title mentioned, I sent js object back to C# IDictionary by cloud function callback, but I got the wrong order.

I using console.log to check the order is correct before sending it in node.js
[image]

But I got the wrong order when I got the data and convert it to IDictionary in C# client(Unity)
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` makes no guarantees around ordering. You shouldn't expect it to preserve order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon also commented, a `Dictionary` in C# (and in most other languages) does not guarantee that the order of its items is maintained. If you need to ensure the items are returned in a specific order, use a `List` instead with a tuple of the key and values.

Comment: When I use a Dictionary, I usually get the right order, so I never think about it. Really helpful, thank you.